# Save two things at the same time - Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am currently developing a system where I store custumer's information... One of these information is the custumer's address. To do so, I create two tables in my database: Address and Custumer. 
I use the address stored in the custumer table as a foreign key... so far so good. The problem is that I need to first save the address and after get the result id (The id is auto increment) and create the query to save the custumer using that id, but I need to do that at the same function using node, unfortunelly, as I try to do so, I get this error:

'Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.'

Below is my code:

```
this.save = function(connection, object, callback){

    let sqlAdress = utilClient.createSaveAdressQuery(object.address);

    connection.query(sqlAdress , (error, results) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        objeto.address.id = results.insertId;

        //After that the address is saved, I try to save the client
        let sql =  utilCliente.createSaveQuery(object);
        connection.query(sql, (callback));
    })

}
```

Does anyone know how to help me out? Thanks in advance!

This my callback code:

```
app.post("/save", function(request, response){

  var custumer = request.body;

  var connection = dbConnection();

  eventoBanco.salvar(connection, custumer, function(error, result){
    response.send(result);
    if(error != null) console.log(error);
  });

  connection.end();
});
```

Comment: What i can see is that your connection is close after you insert the address and when you take your address id to save in other table the connection is quit . I would suggest check the connection object . Read the document of module you use for mysql .

Comment: @Himanshusharma, thanks for your replying,the only moment that I close connection by calling the method 'connection.close' is in the callback that  I pass into the function, note that I just call the callback function after the client has been saved (or at least should be), is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: add callback code here too

Comment: @Himanshusharma, I added the callback in my question, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve that problem by doing so :

```
clienteFactoryDAO.alterar(connection, cliente, function(erro, result){
            response.send(result);
            if(erro != null) console.log(erro);
            connection.end();
});
```

As you can notice now, I close the connection query in the callback passed into the function. MY MISTAKE WAS as the @Himanshusharma nicely pointed: I was closing the connection outside the callback function, and as you know, JavaScript is asynchronous, so it was closing the connection too soon and when I needed one, I got nothing. Thanks in advance and I hope it helps someone at some point